# Bootstrap change font

Tags: fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to make custom bootstrap theme using Pikock Bootstrap Magic. I choose the font, but when I use it, the font didn't change.

Edit:
I link the font via google font separately. Solved^^..

Comment: First, post code to show what you've done. Second, how are you wanting to change teh font scheme? Do youw want to change the font size? Style? Weight? Gotta get specific.

Comment: why not posting your issue at https://github.com/pikock/bootstrap-magic/issues/new?

Answer (score 0):

...... For the record, this is how to override Bootstraps choice of font outside the LESS (or CSS, for that matter):

```
body,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
.h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6,
.tooltip,
.popover {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

This overrides all places where Bootstrap 3.3.5 declares (or re-declares) the base font family.